# why can't i update a record with each separator and field on a new line?

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, f#, record

i'm using the following record type

```
type MyRecord =
    { x : int
    ; y : int
    ; z : int
    }

let r = 
    { x = 0
    ; y = 0
    ; z = 0
    }
```

the following compiles

```
let r' =
    { r with x = r.x+1;
             y = r.y+2
    }
```

but the following

```
let r' =
    { r with x = r.x+1
    ;        y = r.y+2
    }
```

gives compile errors

```
error FS0010: Unexpected symbol ';' in expression. Expected '}' or other token.
error FS0604: Unmatched '{'
error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '}' in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.
```

can anyone explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semicolon must be at least more indented than the with

```
// as is this code won't compile (multiple definition of y)
let r' =
    { r with x = r.x + 1
           ; y = r.y + 2  // correct
         ;   y = r.y + 2  // correct
        ;    y = r.y + 2  // error
    }
```

Alternatively you could replace the with expression with it's equivalent but you then have to be explicit about all the fields (which can be tedious) :

```
let r' = r in // not sure where you would put that bit
    { x = r.x + 1
    ; y = r.y + 2
    ; z = r.z
    }
```

But, as said by rmunn all those semicolons are optional with a vertical alignment

Comment: thanks. that directly answers my question. i think the alternative won't work if you don't assign to z. but it's good to know

Comment: @symbiont true (edited to put z back) you have to put all fields (that's what do record-copy-and-update `with` syntax behind the curtain)

Answer (score 5):

In F#, the semicolons are optional (and, in fact, completely unnecessary) when the record's fields are on separate lines. You could have written:

```
type MyRecord =
    { x : int
      y : int
      z : int
    }

let r = 
    { x = 0
      y = 0
      z = 0
    }
```

and that would compile just fine. Then your `let r' = ...` statement can look like:

```
let r' =
    { r with x = r.x+1
             y = r.y+2
    }
```

The semicolons are only required when you're putting fields on one line. Lists work similarly:

```
let l = [
    1
    2
    3
]
```

is equivalent to:

```
let l = [1; 2; 3]
```

Again, semicolons are only required when the items are on the same line. If they are on different lines, the semicolons are optional.

Comment: thanks. i had no idea that they could be optional in lists and records. i'm not yet sure how i feel about relying on the white space. i appreciate the answer

Comment: @symbiont: if you don't want to get rid of semicolons, I'd strongly recomend to at least put them in 'standard' position, i.e. at the line ends. This makes their function obvious and doesn't hurt readability that much. Also it is a less big step then to omit them.

Comment: @symbiont: I think you should try it. Due to the fairly refined type system and various other compilation rules, in practice it's very difficult to make a whitespace-related mistake without the compiler noticing and stopping you.